# Generate javadoc in maven and then upload via scp?

Tags: maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin, maven-wagon-plugin

I have Maven javadoc plugin working nicely right now, but I do not know how to add it to the remote directory via scp.

How do I transfer the javadoc files via scp, but AFTER they have been generated? Can this automatically happen when I call site:site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maven-javadoc-plugin doesn't attach to any phase/goal by default, you need configure it manually in pom.xml.

See [Generate Javadocs As Part Of Project Reports](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/usage.html):

> To generate javadocs as part of the site generation, you should add the Javadoc Plugin in the  section of your pom:
>
> ```
>  <project>
>     ...
>     <reporting>
>       <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>           <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
>           <version>2.8.1</version>
>           <configuration>
>             ...
>           </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>       </plugins>
>       ...
>     </reporting>
>     ...
>   </project>
> ```
>
> When you execute mvn site, the javadocs will be generated and included in the generated site. A link to the javadocs will be added in the Project Reports menu.

---

Alternatively, if you use maven-release-plugin, javadoc generation (and upload) is automatically handled by default, see [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-releasing.html):

> The following delvierables are created and deployed to local and remoted repositories after the execution of the release:perform goal has finished.
>
> - artifact id-version.jar
>     The binaries for the current release of the project.
> - artifact id-version-javadoc.jar
>     The javadoc explaining the current functionality of the classes within the current release.
> - artifact id-version-source.jar
>     The source code revisions used to build the current release of the project.
> - artifact id-version.pom
>     The contents of the pom.xml file used to create the current release of the project.

---

If you want to attach javadoc generation to some phase/goal other than site, check out [How to deploy Javadoc jar file?](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/faq.html#How_to_deploy_Javadoc_jar_file)