# Add multiple JARs and Javadoc to local Maven repository

Tags: maven, javadoc, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I have a number of JAR files that comprise two different Java SDKs for BOXI R3.1: [BusinessObjects Enterprise Java SDK](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir31/en/boesdk_java_apiRef_12_en.zip) and the [Web Services Consumer Java SDK](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir31/en/wssdk_java_apiRef_12_en.zip).

The BusinessObjects Enterprise Java SDK has a number of 'core' JARs:

```
biarengine.jar
biplugins.jar
cecore.jar
celib.jar
ceplugins_client.jar
ceplugins_core.jar
ceplugins_cr.jar
cereports.jar
cesession.jar
ceutils.jar
corbaidl.jar
ebus405.jar
flash.jar
SL_plugins.jar
logging.jar
pluginhelper.jar
xcelsius.jar
```

and a number of dependencies:

```
asn1.jar
backport-util-concurrent-2.2.jar
certj.jar
commons-logging.jar
derby.jar
freessl201.jar
jsafe.jar
log4j.jar
rascore.jar
sslj.jar
```

The Javadocs are available as a ZIP file.

The situation is similar for the web-services SDK, so I will omit the details.

Goal: package each SDK and its Javadoc as a local, Maven repository (it doesn't appear that SAP is providing a remote one).

Questions:

- can one Maven repository contain multiple JAR files?  The `mvn deploy:deploy-file` plugin seems to only work on a single file: [How to add a jar, source and Javadoc to the local Maven repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386589/how-to-add-a-jar-source-and-javadoc-to-the-local-maven-repository)
- should Javadocs be kept in ZIP format in a Maven repository?
- if i choose to make to repos for a given SDK (i.e. core and dependencies), is specifying the linkage as easy as editing the core repos' configuration file?
- rather than creating a repo for the dependencies, I'm assuming that it would be better to identify and reference existing Maven repos (e.g log4j.jar).  Will this lead me to JAR hell?

Comment: For Javadoc and/or Source generation, see if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336496/generate-javadoc-in-maven-and-then-upload-via-scp/11337260#11337260) helps. Usually I simply use maven-release-plugin as a one-stop solution.

Comment: Can a repository have >1 JAR?

Comment: In addition I use maven-assembly-plugin with maven-release-plugin as a one-stop solution. maven-assembly-plugin can help you build other package like jar, zip or tar.gz with different classifier (for example *-bin.tar.gz, *-jdk5.zip), and automatically installed to repository when doing mvn release:perform.

Answer (score -1):

Yes a maven repo can contain multiple files, you can execute mvn deploy:deploy-file on each one (using -Djavadoc and -Dsources as needed).

To specify dependencies for a jar, create a pom file for it (with dependencies) and use -DpomFile (and omit -DgeneratePom) in mvn deploy:deploy-file.

Yes you should not re-invent the wheel and deploy artifacts to your repository that are already in central.  You can use tools like http://mvnrepository.com to search for your jars (look META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in your jars to find the version).

For more info see: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html.

Comment: Most of the JARs (listed in my question) aren't found at mvnrepository.com.