# Maven dependencies to crystal reports

Tags: java, maven, crystal-reports

Can anyone tell me if crystal report libraries are available on maven repository. If so how to add dependencies for them? 
i.e. Artifact Id, Version etc.

If not, is the only solution adding dependencies by installing individual jars? if so which jars will be needed?

Any response would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689136/add-multiple-jars-and-javadoc-to-local-maven-repository

Answer (score 1):

Those are commercial jar file and as per my knowledge it won't be there in the maven central repository. So you can install individual jars with the following command.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id>(e.g com.xxx.xxx)
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id>(e.g jrcadapter) -Dversion=<version> (you will get it easily) -Dpackaging=<packaging> (jar)
```

P.S- Jar selection is completely upto based on your business/project requirement.